# What about measuring airspeed from control surface forces on the framework?

Tags: airspeed, control-surfaces

I watch a lot of these videos that people make about air disasters.

One factor that seems (or hopefully seemed) to crop up is where pilots get hopelessly confused about airspeed, particularly (it seems) when visibility is poor, including night-time. This includes Air France 447, and many others.

If a jet flies too fast it will eventually disintegrate. As was the case with Lauda Air 004 (not in any way caused by airspeed indication issues): in that case it was seen that the first thing to disintegrate appears to have been the stabilisers, as the jet accelerated downwards, probably to over Mach 1. I believe that the main force responsible was simply the power of the air on these control surfaces.

Obviously the air exerts forces on the wings, stabilisers and rudder assembly. These forces in turn must exert bending forces at the points where these attach to the aircraft framework. Surely the most reliable way of measuring airspeed (or at the very least another indicator that the computers could use to build up a reliable picture) would be to measure such forces? But I'm not aware that any jet does that. Why not?

Comment: AF447 was mainly caused by poor trained pilots and confusing human-machine-interface. Lauda Air 004 by the in-air deployment of a thrust reverser, nobody knows why. In both cases airspeed was not the direct cause of the accident.  "the most reliable way of measuring airspeed would be to measure such forces" have you a source for such claim about reliability?

Comment: prefacing your sentence with "surely" gives me the impression that you are sure of it, and are looking for validation. if you're not sure, maybe you can find a different way to convey that? - aside from that, the way the question is structured gives the impression that you think having a better airspeed measurement would have somehow prevented the accidents you list.

Comment: There wasn't a problem with inaccuracy in airspeed indications in either accident @mikerodent, in both cases airspeed indications were correct. The current method of measuring airspeed is actually very simple and reliable. In any case airspeed isn't as important as the angle of attack in preventing accidents.

Comment: Your assertion that changes in airspeed cause measurable bending where the wings attach to the airframe is deeply flawed.  By the time the wings bend backwards it’s too late, they will have exceeded their yield strength.

Comment: @GdD. I mentioned Lauda 004 only to point out that planes eventually disintegrate due to excess air flow, NOT (AT ANY TIME!) to state that airspeed indications were EVER involved (nor was this implied, IN ANY WAY). But you are completely wrong to assert AF447 did not involve airspeed indicators. And airspeed indicators based on bending moment would not have failed under those circumstances.

Comment: @mikerodent, I suggest you read the AF447  accident report in detail to correct your understanding of events.

Comment: Behind any accident there's a chain of events and all of the rings are needed to get to the final accident and just because there is a start ring doesn't imply that that ring was the weakest.

Comment: @GdD I suggest you read the report. The first incident which occurred, without which the plane would not have crashed, was the freezing of the Pitot tubes.

Answer (score 5):

There are very sensitive strain gauges, they are used in flight testing to measure stresses all over airplanes. The problem with your idea is that strain is not a good measure of airspeed, this is due to there being many other factors, for example changes in g-forces. Changes in the angle of attack will change strain without a change in airspeed, and turbulence would have readings varying wildly. Other factors would include loaded weight, the fuel quantity in the wings, and others.

The only way such a system would work would be to take all those data points and feed them into a complex real-time computer model which would determine the airspeed based on the interaction of all those factors. Complexity is the enemy of reliability, using strain to measure airspeed would likely be far less reliable than the current pitot based system.

Comment: I was just writing the basically same thing  Yes, I can't also think about a place on the aircraft where deformations are only proportional to airspeed... except maybe on the inside of a pitot tube :⁠-⁠)

Comment: Thanks. On the face of it this looks like a powerful objection... but I'm not sure I'm convinced by the reality of the physics. These strain gauges would be measuring strain in the longitudinal direction of the aircraft only. I don't believe the longitudinal forces due to turbulence would ever be comparable to those caused by the forward motion of the plane at 500 mph. I **think** that similar considerations might apply to other G forces, since their entire aircraft would always be subject to the same G forces.

Comment: ... and in fact, "longitudinal forces due to turbulence" means one thing, and one thing only: changes in airspeed, which is what one is trying to measure.

Comment: @mikerodent, you may have to accept that your idea just won't work.

Comment: @GdD Indeed I may, if credible reasoned arguments are put forward showing that it won't work. I haven't seen any yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously the air exerts forces on the wings, stabilisers and rudder
> assembly. These forces in turn must exert bending forces at the points
> where these attach to the aircraft framework. Surely the most reliable
> way of measuring airspeed (or at the very least another indicator that
> the computers could use to build up a reliable picture) would be to
> measure such forces? But I'm not aware that any jet does that. Why
> not?

To measure those forces, there would need to be some sort of [strain gauge](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fiber-optic-sensors-for-health-monitoring-of-%3A-I.-Wood-Brown/2f14ce6a32ae0e00d3227d76bcaf57c311b65db6) at the point where the structure meets the fuselage.  The problem is that because these anchor points are known to be points of potential failure, they are over-engineered to be extremely strong.  Under normal flight conditions the effect of the forces acting on those points is likely to be unmeasurably small.

The standard method of measuring speed in an aircraft is the [pitot-static system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot-static_system), which has proved extremely reliable over the years, from a search for pitot-related  [crashes, accidents and incidents](https://www.avherald.com/h?search_term=pitot&opt=6144&dosearch=1&search.x=19&search.y=14) on AVHerald.com it appears that the most common issues were insect infestations (as a result of inadequate maintenance after being stored during the Covid pandemic) and bird strikes on the pitot tube.  In most cases pitot problems didn't cause any casualties.

In addition to the pitot system, the aircraft will have a GPS/GNSS system that also displays the speed, the Airbus version is described [here](https://www.flightglobal.com/airbus-backs-up-speed-and-altitude-displays/66437.article):

> the speed scale will display the back-up speed information derived
> from the angle of attack

Changing from these, or adding a new system to them is unlikely to increase aircraft safety or improve pilot performance.

Comment: There **IS** at least one adult in the room! Strain gauges, exactly! And indeed you may have said exactly what the flaw with my suggestion is. Although, having said that, I am slightly surprised that in 2022 there should not be strain gauges which act almost at the atomic or at least nano level, able to detect **incredibly** small deflections. I understand about GPS/GNSS (and INS) systems, although as I understand it these cannot measure airspeed, only acceleration, velocity and position relative to Earth (not relative to air through which the plane is passing...).

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7922605/ - "nanostructured" strain gauges, limits of sensitivity thereof, etc.

Comment: @mikerodent - Whether you can measure at the “atomic” level, one must consider the noise in the environment- buffeting, rain, & also that material stiffness is usually affected by temperature leading to a need for temperature compensation. Also any surface that has control surfaces attached would also undergo stain as those surfaces were deflected- the compensation algorithms would be very complex.All to arrive at a value that would likely be compared to a pitot-static-derived value to prove it was correct. There seems to be a lot of downside and no real upside to this approach.

Comment: @Jim Thanks. A similar point was made by GdD in her/his answer. I am not convinced by this point, as the system would be measuring only longitudinal stress, and in reality the forward motion of the plane, and the consequent stresses on the leading edges, would outweigh everything else in this direction. I'm not saying this system would be "better" than Pitot tubes, rather that the longitudinal strain is clearly a pure function of the force caused by the on-coming air. We can be certain that birds do not have Pitot tubes, but clearly they must sense the strain on their wings.

Comment: @mikerodent - Yes, but as an elevator deflects upward or downward it not only produces a moment about the pitch axis it also increases the drag along the longitudinal axis. This will also be measured by the strain gauge. And it would not know whether this was from increased airspeed or control deflection.

Comment: Just as you don’t have a pitot but can judge how fast you’re going based on the wind in your face. But I would posit that you aren’t judging that by the strain in your neck muscles but by the pressure hitting your face- much more akin to a pitot tube than a strain gauge.

Comment: @Jim good point about the elevators, which also applies to the other control surfaces, such as the flaps and the rudder. However, the degree to which this would influence the drag would also be, like the strain produced longitudinally by the airflow, a pure, i.e. completely predictable, function of the commanded changes to geometry. This would of course increase the complexity of the measurement function but not by much.

Comment: @Jim you're right about the wind in the face being equivalent to Pitot tubes. But I didn't mention faces, I mentioned how birds sense motion through air in their wings: it is obvious that the faster they fly the greater the exertion they will find themselves having to make with their muscles to keep their wings functional. That is a function of the strain caused by airflow. I don't know whether any research has been attempted on this subject, but I surmise that a bird can measure windspeed more accurately by muscle strain than by (e.g.) hairs in their nostrils (functioning like Pitot tubes).

Comment: PS obviously the latter observation does not apply when a bird's wings are folded back and it is in "plummet" mode (I include this remark because I have an uncanny sense that someone in this forum might think they had found a "gotcha" with this point!).